# How to get file name without file extension?

Tags: php, file, string

I have this PHP code:

```
function ShowFileExtension($filepath)
{
    preg_match('/[^?]*/', $filepath, $matches);
    $string = $matches[0];

    $pattern = preg_split('/\./', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    if(count($pattern) > 1)
    {
        $filenamepart = $pattern[count($pattern)-1][0];
        preg_match('/[^?]*/', $filenamepart, $matches);
        return strtolower($matches[0]);
    }
}
```

If I have a file named `my.zip`, this function returns `.zip`.

I want to do the reverse, I want the function to return `my` without the extension.

The file is just a string in a variable.

Answer (score 511, accepted):

No need for all that. Check out [**pathinfo()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), it gives you all the components of your path.

```
$filename = pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

will give you the filename without extension.

Some other examples from the manual:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/index.html');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // filename is only since PHP 5.2.0
```

Output of the code:

```
/www/htdocs
index.html
html
index
```

And alternatively you can get only certain parts like:

```
echo pathinfo('/www/htdocs/index.html', PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // outputs html
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The answer is absolutely correct. pathinfo operates on strings, so it doesn't matter if the file is actually on the server or not.

Comment: It's unfortunate that they misnamed "basename", since it returns the full filename with extension, not the base name.

Comment: @Oscar it is the most widely understood meaning of the term `basename`. No misnaming.

Comment: This is very useful, especially when you don't need to know the file extension in order to extract it.

Comment: This is an extremely elegant solution. Kudos. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Be aware that this will provide wrong information with multiple dot extensions like .tar.gz

Comment: This worked great for me. Thanks for this single line solution.

Answer (score 224):

As an alternative to [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), you can use

- [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) — Returns filename component of path

Example from PHP manual

```
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
```

You have to know the extension to remove it in advance though.

However, since your question suggests you have the need for getting the extension *and* the basename, I'd vote [Pekka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183486/php-code-hid-the-from-the-extension-file-name/2183512#2183512) as the most useful one, because it will give you any info you'd want about the path and file with one single native function.

Comment: what if i do not know about file extension .. let say if path is dynamic anytype of file extension can come in it !! then what ??

Comment: @user889030 then you have a different scenario than the OP and don't use `basename`, but `pathinfo` as shown elsewere on the page.

Answer (score 131):

https://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Simple functional test: https://ideone.com/POhIDC

Comment: Whoever decided that `filename` doesn't have an extension while `basename` does must have some sadistic tendencies...

Comment: Look at all you gloating young hipsters with your fancy pants 32bits. Back in my day we was lucky to have 8bits for the entire operating system; nevermind naming files and such. Spoild rotten - the lot of you. Hexadecimal i say. Hex! A hex on all your houses! Then let's see ya'll whining about how to find your silly file handler extensions! Anyhow @yckart Thanks. love a nice one liner

Answer (score 19):

Another approach is by using regular expressions.

```
$fileName = basename($filePath);
$fileNameNoExtension = preg_replace("/\.[^.]+$/", "", $fileName);
```

This removes from the last period `.` up until the end of the string.

Comment: Much better than using explode, and only catches the last period section in case you used periods in file names

Comment: **No**, it's much much worse. Stop regexing people.

Comment: Thanks, and the above comments nailed it. Not having to know the extension makes this more useful.

Comment: @Pacerier Could you give any reason as to why it's much worse?

Comment: @caiosm1005, The attack surface immediately increases because It's hard to reason against the internals of a regex engine. For example, in the code above, it wouldn't be odd if there's some input `$fileName` which could cause the engine to run in exponential (or worse) time. And assuming we have finished dissecting the internals of this specific regex engine and have theoretically proven it to be robust against every possible value `$fileName` could be, the code is still not arbitrarily portable to another platform that has another implementation of the regex engine.

Comment: @Pacerier I have to disagree. Firstly, this is a very simple regex; I just can't see how the processing time could increase exponentially. Secondly, there are no special wildcards in this expression, so it should be able to run the same in any regex implementation.

Answer (score 15):

If the extension is not known, use this solution

```
 pathinfo('D:/dir1/dir2/fname', PATHINFO_FILENAME); // return "fname"
 pathinfo('D:/dir1/dir2/fname.php', PATHINFO_FILENAME); // return "fname"
 pathinfo('D:/dir1/dir2/fname.jpg', PATHINFO_FILENAME); // return "fname"

 pathinfo('D:/dir1/dir2/fname.jpg', PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . '/' . pathinfo('D:/dir1/dir2/fname.jpg', PATHINFO_FILENAME); // return "D:/dir1/dir2/fname"
```

[PHP MAN function pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: Please provide a like to the php man page for `pathinfo`. This is going to help OP make the `ShowFileExtension` method better and will provide extra reading for anyone trying to find this answer. Also a bit of a description would not go astray...

Comment: I have answered this question already with the same solution, ~2 years before yours ;)

Comment: @yckart true but this does give multiple examples within the answer. Yours has the benefit of linking to ideone.com but the site could go offline.

Answer (score 8):

Almost all the above solution have the shown getting filename from variable $path

Below snippet will **get the current executed file name without extension**

```
echo pathinfo(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

**Explanation**

> $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] contains the path of the current script.

Answer (score 6):

@Gordon basename will work fine if you know the extension, if you dont you can use explode:

```
$filename = end(explode(".", $file));
```

Comment: Please direct comments to me with the comment function below my answer. The most appropriate function for this is `pathinfo`, which is why I gave `basename` as an alternative only. There is no need to reinvent `pathinfo` with regex or `explode`.

Comment: @fire, Your update makes no sense. `end(explode(".", $file));` gives you the extension, not the filename.

Answer (score 3):

@fire incase the filename uses dots, you could get the wrong output.
I would use @Gordon method but get the extension too, so the basename function works with all extensions, like this:

```
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$file = basename($path, ".".$ext); // $file is set to "index"
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case, i use below. I don't care what is its extention. :D
i think it will help you

```
$exploded_filepath = explode(".", $filepath_or_URL);
$extension = end($exploded_filepath);
echo basename($filepath_or_URL, ".".$extension ); //will print out the the name without extension.
```

Comment: Btw.: You have a typo in `$extenion`

Answer (score 2):

Short

```
echo pathinfo(__FILE__)['filename']; // since php 5.2
```

Comment: good. But if i put above code in `b.php` and i executed `a.php` having `require('b.php')`. Then output will how `b` instead of `a`

Comment: almost there : echo pathinfo($filename_with_extension)['filename'];

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes an extension contains more than one part. It may or may not be desirable to remove the entire extension. The function below removes the entire extension if you pass `true` as the second parameter:

```
function removeExt($path, $fullExt = false)
{
    if ($fullExt === false)
         return pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $basename = basename($path);
    return strpos($basename, '.') === false ? $path : substr($path, 0, - strlen($basename) + strlen(explode('.', $basename)[0]));
}
```

Eg:

```
echo removeExt('https://example.com/file.php');
// https://example.com/file
echo removeExt('https://example.com/file.tar.gz');
// https://example.com/file.tar
echo removeExt('https://example.com/file.tar.gz', true);
// https://example.com/file
echo removeExt('file.tar.gz');
// file.tar
echo removeExt('file.tar.gz', true);
// file
echo removeExt('file');
// file
```

Comment: Better to use strripos instead of stripos, to avoide dots in file name.

Comment: @KhalidAlmannai Using `strripos` would fail to remove the full extension. It would remove `.gz`, instead of `.tar.gz`. In some cases it maybe desirable to only remove the last part of the extension but not always.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: @KhalidAlmannai I've updated my answer to allow for either removing part of the extension or the full extension, based on an optional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

File name without file extension when you don't know that extension:

`$basename = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, "."));`

Comment: How about if the extension is something like .tar.gz ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know which extension you have, then you can try this:

```
$ext = strtolower(substr('yourFileName.ext', strrpos('yourFileName.ext', '.') + 1));
echo basename('yourFileName.ext','.'.$ext); // output: "youFileName" only
```

Working with all possibilities:

```
image.jpg // output: "image"
filename.image.png // output: "filename.image"
index.php // output: "index"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this

```
$filename = current(explode(".", $file));
```

These will return current element of array, if not used before.

Comment: Hello, Pleas e check before downgrading it. It is working I had used it in my code many a times. By using this function you can get just a file name If you file name is "xyz.jpg". 
It may not work with file names containing entire path in it.

Comment: This also doesn't work correctly if a filename has multiple dots in it, e.g. "some.interesting.image.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

This return only filename without any extension in 1 row:

```
$path = "/etc/sudoers.php";    
print array_shift(explode(".", basename($path)));
// will print "sudoers"

$file = "file_name.php";    
print array_shift(explode(".", basename($file)));
// will print "file_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is below the perfect solution to hide to file extension in php.

```
<?php
    $path = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    echo basename($path, ".php");
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

File extension extract from file:

```
File Name = subrotobiswas.jpg
$fileExtension = pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //Output: jpg
$newNameOfFileWithoutExtension = basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], $fileExtension ); //Output: subrotobiswas
$fullFileName = $newNameOfFileWithoutExtension . "." .$fileExtension; // Output: subrotobiswas.jpg
```