# What Regex for this?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I try a regex, but the result is not really that I want.

This is my regex :

```
/^(([a-z]{0,})([0-9]+)).*/i
```

And this is my strings :

```
8500A.JPG //I need to get 8500A but I get 8500
0130799.JPG // I get the good result : 0130799
```

How to keep alphabetical characters before the .JPG ?

Comment: The expression matches everyting, in which group do you need `8500A`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Get File Name Without File Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183486/php-get-file-name-without-file-extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may have been getting enclosing parenthesis confused.

inside the character class you can specify many ranges

```
/^([0-9A-Za-z]{0,})\.JPG$/
```

To break down what it is doing:

- ^ = start of line
- $ = end of line
- (...) = $1 will get anything in here
- [A-Za-z0-9] = match anything between A-Z, between a-z and between 0-9
- {0,} = 0 or more times
- . = escape so you use a literal "."

More info here:
http://www.regextester.com/pregsyntax.html

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
/^(\w+).*?\.\w+$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
/^(([a-z]{0,})([0-9]+)([a-z]*)).*/i
```

What exactly do you need?

Comment: It works for me, thanks !

I need to clean strings from extension

Comment: In this case you don't need regular expression. Just use `$pos = strrpos($text, '.'); if ($pos !== false) $text = substr($text, 0, $pos);`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this simple regexp is correct

```
/^([a-z0-9]+)\.*/i
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/^(([a-z]*)([0-9]+.*?))\..*$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
$pattern = "/^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*).*$/";
preg_match($pattern, "8500A.JPG", $matches);
echo $matches[1];       

preg_match($pattern, "0130799.JPG", $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

The output will be:

```
8500A
0130799
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to strip extensions from file name, why not use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)?

```
$filename = pathinfo($yourfile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

In your case:

```
echo pathinfo('8500A.JPG',PATHINFO_FILENAME);
echo pathinfo('0130799.JPG',PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

outputs:

```
8500A
0130799
```

This is *WAY EASIER AND CLEANER* than using regex!