# PHP RegEx extract filename

Tags: php, regex

I need your help with a RegEx in PHP

I have something like:
vacation.jpg and I am looking for a RegEx which extracts me only the 'vacation' of the filename.
Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Get File Name Without File Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183486/php-get-file-name-without-file-extension)

Comment: You do not need regular expression for this - PHP has built-in features that enable you to do this without regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a regex for this - use [`basename`](https://www.php.net/basename):

```
$fileName = basename($fullname, ".jpg");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) instead of Regex.

```
$file = 'vacation.jpg';
$path_parts = pathinfo($file);
$filename = $path_parts['filename'];

echo $filename;
```

Answer (score 2):

And if you really need regex, this one will do it:

```
$success = preg_match('~([\w\d-_]+)\.[\w\d]{1,4}~i', $original_string, $matches);
```

Inside matches you will have first part of file name.

Answer (score 1):

Better answers have already been provided, but here's another alternative!

```
$fileName = "myfile.jpg";
$name = str_replace(substr($fileName, strpos($fileName,".")), "", $fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this.

Approach 1:

```
$str = 'vacation.jpg';
$parts = explode('.', basename($str));
if (count($parts) > 1) array_pop($parts);
$filename = implode('.', $parts);
```

Approach 2 (better, use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)):

```
$str = 'vacation.jpg';
$filename = pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```