# PHP remove certain group of characters from string

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Get File Name Without File Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183486/php-get-file-name-without-file-extension)

Using php, how would I remove a certain set of characters from a string. For example I want to go from:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/image.gif
```

to

```
image
```

I want to remove everything except the name of the image.

Comment: Look into [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) and/or [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url).

Answer (score 0):

So you just want the filename? use `pathinfo()`.

```
$name = pathinfo('http://www.domain.com/folder/image.gif', PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the downvote?