# Get the title of a file into a string WITHOUT the extension

Tags: php, string

I am trying to get the title of a file into a string WITHOUT the extension. I understand how `end()` works... but i want the FRONT of the string removed. I can't find something in the PHP manual that directs me into the right direction. ANY help will be appreciated.

Example:

```
$fileName = $_FILES["video"]["name"];
The file name $fileType = explode('.',$fileName);
$fileType = end($fileType);
$origFileName = "<(??????)>"
```

found my problem. added:

> $fileOrigName = basename($fileName,$fileType);
>   $fileOrigName = substr($fileOrigName, 0, -1);

TY for all your comments and help :)

Comment: if you do explode the file name on dot you can then easily get the last portion to have the extension

Comment: i know the file extension. i want to REMOVE the extension from the string and rename it

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, get file name without file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183486/php-get-file-name-without-file-extension)

Comment: TY... that was the rigt direction i was looking at @caCtus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php). It does exactly what you want.