# Substring between two different characters?

Tags: php, string, substring

I'm looking for a way to get a substring in php. Given string is:
"abc/def/ghi/name.extension"

I only want to have 'name', and the number of forward slashes is not known and not the same number either. Tried it with substring, but I get stuck in the elimination of the /

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2183486/134824

Comment: STOP answering 5 is enough only one of them is any good

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate anyway rather than answering something that has already been answered.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$str = "abc/def/ghi/name.extension";
$name = \pathinfo( $str, \PATHINFO_FILENAME );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. First split the string into an array with `explode ()` and then split the last element by the dot.

```
$a = 'abc/def/ghi/name.extension';
$b = explode ('/', $a);
$b = $b[count ($b) - 1];
$c = explode ('.', $b)[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this for filename.

```
$filename = pathinfo("abc/def/ghi/name.extension", PATHINFO_FILENAME);
echo $filename;
```

and this for file extension.

```
$ext = pathinfo("abc/def/ghi/name.extension", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $ext;
```