# how to cut off string in php5.6.40 or higher,when i can control var from $_GET?

Tags: php

I RENT a website, i found a position that i can control the var from $_GET and then the server will exec the function "move_uploaded_file(filename,destination)", the question is how to cut off the '.jpg', thanks a lot.

the php version is 5.6.40 or heigher
the os is cloudlinux , centos7.6

```
$temp_str = $_GET['str'];
$destination = '/tmp/'.$temp_str.'.jpg';
move_uploaded_file(filename,$destination);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just remove the `.'.jpg'` from `$destination = '/tmp/'.$temp_str.'.jpg';`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah, exactly what I though. Unless both of us are missing something. What do you expect $temp_str to look like, and do you do any validation besides this?

Comment: just about CTF，i tried "test.php\x00.jpg"，burp hex "20"=>"00"，before php 5.6.7 it can work，but after， doesn't work。

Comment: i tried all the way in this post  (https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/) ，doesn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183486/php-get-file-name-without-file-extension. You need to use php function to get filename without extension

Comment: eeeeeeeeeeeeeee...